# Recommendations for On-Hand 74xx (and others?) ICs

Tags: logic-gates, ttl

I've been learning about logic gates (from Ben Eater's videos, etc.) and I find myself constantly having to order more ICs, especially 74xxs. Is there a list of ones I should keep on hand to help avoid unnecessary delays from ordering.

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/966/which-electronics-components-should-i-always-have-on-hand) helped a lot but it didn't seem to cover logic gates.

Comment: Well you either order every single one ever made or you watch all the videos and make a note of what to order and order them.

Comment: I was just wondering if there were common ones that everyone should have on-hand.

Comment: Well, if you have enough 7400s you can make pretty much any sort of gate from them.

Comment: A note, if you're following along with Ben Eater's videos: you can't just hook up LEDs directly to the output of just any old 74 series chip without a resistor; it's fine with the 74LS series that Eater uses, but you'll burn out your LEDs if you do it with a 74HC or other CMOS logic chip. Try to get 74LS or 74ALS where you can if you want to be able to do that (which is very handy for making a breadboard computer, not so much for other purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot depends on what you want to do.

I like to keep a fair amount of [glue logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glue_logic) around. My most common use parts are '00 (NAND), '32 (OR), 08 (AND), '04 (NOT), '06 (open collector inverters) and '14 (inverters with schmitt trigger inputs) and I really like the [SN74LVC1G99](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G99) configurable logic gate from which you can implement *many* boolean functions.

I do keep a few bus latches / drivers around for interfacing projects. ('244. '245, '373 and the 16 bit variants).

There are some items apart from that, but those are the parts I personally use the most.

There will always be a few parts I do not have to hand, but I can usually get them within a day anyway.

Comment: This was exactly the input I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe throw in a few '73 or '74 flip-flops too?

Comment: I remember getting excited in 1976 finding a [7489](http://makeyourownchip.tripod.com/7489.pdf) in the works stores cupboard. Not any more though.

Comment: I don't really use that many '73, '74 or '76 devices (although I have a few in the trays). Ah - the 7489 brings back memories. Sometimes an amusing datasheet appears, though. https://www.baldengineer.com/links/signetics-write-memory-25120-datasheet

Comment: @Finbarr I actually ordered a grab bag of 74xxs from Jameco and there were 18 74AS74s and 1 74AC74 in it.

Comment: @PeterSmith But you're probably using these for actual designs. I'd say for someone learning and experimenting with logic circuits they're much more of an essential.